# what is the best and worst case analysis of these algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, big-o, time-complexity

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
int i=n; 
while(i>1) {
    Console.Write(i); 
    i%=2; 
}
```

and

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
int x=0; 
for(int i=0;i<=n;++i) 
{  
    for(int j=0;j<=i;++j) 
    { 
        for(k=1;k<=n;k++) 
        { 
            x++; 
        } 
    }
}
```

and

```
int n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int x=0,y=1;
for( int i=n; i > 1 ; i /= 3 )
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j*=5)
    { 
        x++; 
        if ( x < n/2 )
            y*=2;
        else
            y--; 
    }
```

as far as i know the big O for the first piece of code is O(1) regardless of the input *n* and for the second piece of code it would be O(n^3) again regardless of the input, i'm not sure about the third piece of code though!. but our teacher asked us the best and worst cases! there is no best or worst! am i right?

Comment: This is really hard to read. Please edit the post and format it properly.

Comment: Worst case should be `O(N*N*I)` and so the best case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block should iterate twice at most.

For the second block:

[image]

For the third block (Look at the last slides of this [document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> as far as i know the big O for the first piece of code is O(1) regardless of the input n and for the second piece of code it would be O(n^3) again regardless of the input. but our teacher asked us to best and worst cases! there is no best or worst! am i right?

Yes, that's right.

```
while(i>1) {
    i%=2; 
}
```

This is going to complete immediately. Any number that you mod by zero will give you either 1 or zero.

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;++i) 
{  
    for(int j=0;j<=i;++j) 
    { 
        for(k=1;k<=n;k++) 
        { 
        } 
    }
}
```

This looks like `O(n^3)` to me. The outer loop happens `n` times, the middle loop happens an average of `n/2` times for each time the outer loop occurs, and the inner loop happens `n-1` times for every time the outer loop occurs. `n * 2n * (n-1)`  simplifies to `O(n^3)`.

Worst and best case are the same for both of these: you can't really pick a series of numbers to input that are going to cause the complexity to not follow the same asymptotic pattern as they get larger.

Comment: what about the third code? i don't really know how that works! (i guess it would be O(n^2) but thats just a guess) . could you help me with that plz :(

Comment: @user3568592: No, because I'm not a fan of how you're using StackOverflow. It's obvious you're just using us to get answers to your homework. You don't bother to format your code, and even after people answer your question, you just change it to add more questions. You've had multiple people complain about some of these problems, and instead of responding to them or improving the quality of your questions, you just keep doing the same thing. Do your own homework, and if you come up against a specific concern, take time to write a quality question about it.